# Is there a way to recover a bad/broken USB hard disk (not the data, just the disk)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, usb

I have an old USB hard drive that I use to make nightly backups (using rsync). But it seems to have "broken".

I am running Ubuntu Server LTS (20.04) headless, and didn't notice until I had to connect a monitor (for unrelated reason), and saw some errors like

```
blk_update_request critical medium error
```

and

```
buffer i/o error on dev ssd
```

If I run `sudo fdisk -l`, it prints out a bunch of stuff for other drives, but freezes at a certain point (I'm guessing while trying to access that drive) until I physically unplug it.

I can run `lsusb -v`, and it shows up:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bc2 Seagate RSS LLC
  idProduct          0x3320 SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2
  iProduct                3
  iSerial                 1
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0055
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
```

`lsblk` shows:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdd      8:48   0   3.9G  0 disk
```

It is a 3TB disk.

I unplugged the drive, and have tried connecting to my MacBook, but it doesn't show up under diskutil (`diskutil list` doesn't list it).

Reconnecting it to the Ubuntu server, I can see `sdd` show up under `/dev/`, but it doesn't show up with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` (or any other `/dev/disk/by-*`).

If I use `sudo fdisk /dev/sdd`, it hangs at:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
```

So is there another method to try, so that I can use this drive again? I'm (as you can guess from the above) fine with formatting and loosing the data, I'll just rsync again. But of course, if there's a way that retains the data, that's (slightly) preferable.

Comment: Many times the enclosure is bad, remove the drive from the enclosure, connect to pc using a usb hard drive adapter, see if the drive is good,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used a lot of these. In my experience, once broken, they are not worth trying to keep.

Any attempt to format, if it were to succeed (normally not) will leave you with an unreliable drive.

Just replace it.

If you have a number of these, make a schedule to replace them over time.